# Is it possible for an autoscaling group scale based on CPUReservation for instances within that autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I have an ECS cluster that is composed of multiple autoscaling groups. I'd like to autoscale based on CPUReservations, but so far I've only found how to autoscale based on the CPUReservations for the entire ECS cluster rather than the CPUReservations for that autoscaling group within the cluster. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've read in the docs, it is not possible to do this out-of-the-box. You will need to push custom metrics to Cloudwatch and reference these metrics instead of the built-in CPUReservation/MemoryReservation.